# How to create the "dead jedi" sound effect

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound-effects-recording

Seconds 2-4 from

of "Use the force Luke".

It's a trailing echo, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve it as I'm relatively new to sound design.  I'm using Audacity as my editor.

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic audio effect called reverberation.

In audacity go to the effect tab and select reverb.

There are lots of different types of reverbs, with lots of settings. You will have to use trial and error to emulate the exact same reverb.